# keycode 13 and keycode 10 not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit, keypress, keycode

Event `keypress` 13 and 10 not working on iPhone safari, android firefox but working with android default browser.

I have a jsp page which has a form which that takes a number as input and changes values of other div elements in the same page by dividing those numbers by this input.

I am using `keypress` function of jQuery and testing with keycode 10 and 13 for this. It's working on all desktop browsers but the GO button doesn't fire on safari and firefox on smart phones. Please let me know how to go about this?

Here is the partial code I have used:

```
$('.number').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 10 || e.keyCode == 13 ) {

        $('#1').html((textreplace/input).toFixed(0)+'g');
        $('#2').html((textreplace2/input).toFixed(0)+'%');
        $('#3').html((textreplace3/input).toFixed(0)+'g');
        ...
        ..

    }
}
```

The ".number" is the class name used in the input form which has type="text". So, basically I am not using submit at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `keyup` and `keydown`. `keypress` event is not really ideal.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try and get back to you!